# How to use Regex with jQuery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, regex

I am using

```
  Regex re = new Regex("[;\\/:~+%^#@&*?\"<>|&']");
        strFileName = re.Replace(strFileName, "_");
```

operation in c#.

I need to use same regex with jquery operation

```
var strFileName = strFileName .replace(/[^-0-9a-zA-Z.]/g, "_");
```

But it is not working.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Define "not working".

Comment: I mean var strFileName = strFileName .replace(/[^-0-9a-zA-Z.]/g, "_"); It doesn't replace "-","(" sign

Comment: Is this a javascript question or a jQuery question?  I don't see any jQuery in your question.

Comment: Soory fren...It should be like this var strFileName = strFileName .replace(/[^-0-9a-zA-Z.]/g, "_");

Comment: What happens for a specific string, and what did you want to happen?

Comment: I want to replace special character with "_" (Underscore) sign.Its is working fine with c# Code (  Regex re = new Regex("[;\\/:~+%^#@&*?\"<>|&']");).but i need to do same with jquery .

Comment: I understand that bit. Give an example of a string that fails.

Comment: var strFileName ="images (6).jpg"   Now i need                       var strFileName ="images_ _6_.jpg"

Comment: @BijayaKhadka - per the logic of your code `"images (6).jpg"` will be converted to `"images__6_.jpg"` as each separate illegal char will be replaced with an underscore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I try this:

```
var strFileName = "whatever%#.jpg$";
strFileName = strFileName.replace(/[^\0-9a-zA-Z.]/g, "_");
alert(strFileName);
```

it gives me `"whatever__.jpg_"`.

Per your other test case supplied, if I put in `"wh-atever%#.jpg$"`, I had to remove the first dash from your regex to get it to produce your desired output of `"wh_atever__.jpg_"`.

See working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/r5V9d/

If this is not working for you, then perhaps you have a script error somewhere else that is preventing this script from working (check the browser error console for script errors) or there is something else going on in your code that you have not disclosed.

Comment: @Floris - just a typo that I removed.

Comment: I agree with you. This works, even for the string OP gave. Error is not in the code given. I do wonder about the space in his statement... `strFileName .replace`

Comment: what if var strFileName = "wh-atever%#.jpg$"; Now i need same result  ie "wh_atever__.jpg_"

Comment: Then your replace function would be strFileName.replace(/[^0-9a-zA-Z.]/g, "_");

Comment: @BijayaKhadka - if you want dashes convert to underscores too, then remove the first dash from your regex as I show in my answer.  See here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/pkJgG/

Comment: @jfriend00 - might as well get rid of '-' from your replace function, for the OP to mark it as an answer. Agreed, his question wasn't complete.

Comment: @NomadTraveler - I already did.

Answer (score 1):

from your reply to the comments, it seems that you have some special characters that is not replaced, you can use your first regex after applying minor tweaks to it, this is a modified version of yours

```
var thumbnail = "test%#$#\\^:-(filename.jpg";
thumbnail  = thumbnail .replace(/[;\\/:~+%^#@&*?\"<>|&'\$\-\(\)]/g, "_")
```

and thumbnail will be `"test_________filename.jpg"`
give it a try